# Data access in Silverlight 2.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, silverlight, data-binding

I'm new to silverlight and I'm porting from asp.net 2.0. I have done many data binding applications in asp.net where I use sql server 2005 and use it's tables and access them via sqlconnection object and perform all kind of database related functions. Can anyone tell does silverlight 2.0 supports such kind of facility. If so can I use any database server, if not is it through web services? can anyone point me some good place to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight is a client side technology. You can't access a database on the server directly. You have to use a layer in between, like webservices. For a nice tutorial on how to do that, check http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No you can't connect directly to a database server. You need to use a web service. However to simplify things you can call a data web service such as SQL Server Data Services or Amazon S3. Otherwise use [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).